# Error durante el descifrado al crear cuenta en correo electrónico de base de datos

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentando configurar el envío de correos electrónicos desde el servicio de base de datos SQL SERVER 2008 a través de su característica "Correo electrónico de base de datos", pero al momento de crear una cuenta de correo electrónico, el procedimiento me retorna como error el mensaje "Error durante el descifrado".

La cuenta que intento registrar es una de prueba del servicio Gmail, información que ya he utilizado en aplicaciones .NET para envío de correos con SmtpClient (por lo que la información de conexión y cuenta son válidos).

Lo extraño de esto es que cuando intento nuevamente editar la información de la cuenta en SQL SERVER, los datos que ingresé de Gmail (nombre de servidor, puerto, autenticación básica), se pierden, quedando con el nombre del servidor SQL, el puerto 25, y autenticación anónima.

He leído que supuestamente hay algún problema con el SMK, pero no tengo idea al respecto de esta característica, por lo que agradeceré si alguien pudiera orientarme al respecto del por qué se genera este problema en la configuración.

---

No se puede actualizar la cuenta xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx para el servidor SMTP Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SQLiMailServer.

---

INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:

Error de Establecer contraseña de inicio de sesión del servidor de correo para MailServer 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Para obtener ayuda, haga clic en: [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.5500.0+((Katmai_PCU_Main).110921-2358+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Establecer+contraseña+de+inicio+de+sesión+del+servidor+de+correo+MailServer&LinkId=20476](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.5500.0+((Katmai_PCU_Main).110921-2358+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Establecer+contrase%C3%B1a+de+inicio+de+sesi%C3%B3n+del+servidor+de+correo+MailServer&LinkId=20476)

---

Excepción al ejecutar una instrucción o un proceso por lotes Transact-SQL. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Error durante el descifrado. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15466)

Para obtener ayuda, haga clic en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15466&LinkId=20476

---

Ambos links ofrecidos por el mismo SQL SERVER ya no están operativos...

Comment: dice descifrado o cifrado?

Comment: @gbianchi "Error durante el descifrado (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15466)"
Ese es el motivo del error. Incluiré el error completo.